# Word for that which is symbolized by a symbol

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that indicates that which is symbolized by a symbol. This is coming from a computer science background where the terms `L-value(left value)` and `R-value(right value)` are often used in the context of defining symbols in a compiler for statements that define symbols such as:

```
A = 1
```

which defines the symbol A as the number 1. However that which is assigned to the symbol need not be a number in general.

An example sentence where this word could be used is.

```
Each entry in the table contains a symbol and its corresponding ____________.
```

One obvious choice is the the word `value` however that is a bit too vague in this context.

Comment: Why do you consider _value_ as too vague?

Comment: If this weren't a computer thing, I'd say ['signified'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_(semiotics)), from classic Saussurian semiotics, or for normal people 'meaning'.

Comment: @alwayslearning It is difficult for me to articulate why the word `value` is too vague. The best I can do is to say that often I find it necessary refer to a collection of `definitions` without mentioning the associated symbol, and each `definition` may in fact correspond to more than one symbol. In those cases I want the word to imply that there is one or more symbols  that correspond with it. Simply stating `value` in the absence of specifying a symbol, does not imply the existence of a symbol.

Comment: @alwayslearning In programming, a `value` is something very broad. Anything that makes sense has a `value` somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you are essentially imitating the operation of a dictionary and you don't want to use current programming language (key:value), I believe 'definition' would be appropriate.

Comment: Personally I think "meaning" would be even better

Answer (score 1):

Referent.

That's a general word for "what a symbol refers to". There might also be some better choice of noun which is more informative in the context where you want to say this.